# python - shortcut to refer to other arguments in a function call

Tags: python

I want to clean-up some code.

I have a lot of boilerplate code in this form:

`func("string", local_dict["string"])`

Is there some shortcut I can use to refer to `"string"` so I don't have to repeat it?

With regular expressions, if you surround parts of the regex with parentheses, you can refer to those parts in the regex using the syntax `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: What about `global_dict` and `func("string")`?

Comment: So, your `"string"` could take different values and you want to change all those `strings`? Or, the whole line?

Comment: Are you opening up some files with such function definitions, reading in as text, and then trying to pattern match those `"string"`s, so you could replace them with whatever you like?

Comment: The only problem with your regex idea is that you are now writing functions that take what looks like a single parameter, but in reality could be a lot. Moreover, each function now has to use a regex to split the parameters. So in the end you have just moved the problem from your parameter list to repeated regex split in all functions

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand the background of the question, but the variable is the one created for such a case.

You can store the value to a variable to avoid the repetitive typing of the same things. It should work as you expect.

```py
s = "string"
func(s, local_dict[s])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to supply a bit more info about your situation. If you can change the function you can change what you pass to it like

```
func(name, obj):
    member = obj[name]
    ...
```

you can proxy the func:

```
func(name, obj):
    _func(member, obj[name])
    ...
```

You can wrap the func:

```
wrap = lambda x,y: x(y, local_dict[y])
wrap(func, "string")
```

There are probably some more things you can do if you can provide more info

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for something like this. In case my answer does not address the problem, please leave a note and I will either modify it or delete it.

## Solution

I assume that you have such function definitions `func("string", local_dict["string"])` in a file. And you are trying to read the text from the file and then modify specifically the `"string"` part of the function definitions.

```py
import re
text = """
func("string", local_dict["string"])
func("bing", local_dict["tring"])
func("ping", local_dict["bling"])
func("sing", local_dict["bring"])
"""
#print(text)

funcs = re.findall('(func\(\")([a-zA-Z+]*)("\s*[,]\s*local_dict\[\")([a-zA-Z+]*)(\"\s*\]\s*[)]\s*)', text)
funcs
```

**Output**:

```
[('func("', 'string', '", local_dict["', 'string', '"])\n'),
 ('func("', 'bing', '", local_dict["', 'tring', '"])\n'),
 ('func("', 'ping', '", local_dict["', 'bling', '"])\n'),
 ('func("', 'sing', '", local_dict["', 'bring', '"])\n')]
```

### Access the `"string"`s

```py
for func in funcs:
    print('$1: {}, $2: {}'.format(func[1], func[3]))
```

**Output**:

```
$1: string, $2: string
$1: bing, $2: tring
$1: ping, $2: bling
$1: sing, $2: bring
```